# Use custom meta box to display alert on front page Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm trying to use a custom meta box with a checkbox to display content (an alert) on the front page. The site I'm making is a online video solution for a small firm where they have occasional live broadcasting. When they have live broadcasting I would like the user to be able to use a checkbox to display some content on the front page to let the readers know that they are sending live.

Does anyone know if/how this is possible? I'm using regular posts to add a live page if that is relevant.

Comment: How do you use "regular posts to add a live page"?

Comment: The end user will add the livestream through a video-player at the "new post" section. Hope this is understandable!

Comment: No, that doesn't really tell me what you are doing. Are you just adding a new post for each "live" stream? That doesn't make sense. How long is it actually live? An hour? How do you switch it back off so that it isn't "live" anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is having the same issue as me I thought I would post my solution.

I made a custom post type live-tv so that the user can add the live broadcasting there. When a post is published I have a loop on the front page that gets only one post (they only have one live broadcast at the time) and then style the front end as I want.

I understand that this was a difficult question to wrap your minds around and I'm terrible at explaining. But thanks for trying to help.